# Vue async bind data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I've read a lot of posts about this topic. But its different in my situation.

Based on my json data, i'll load my components. 
Only if its type is multiple, i need to fire a function that gets an array async.

my situation

```html
<div v-for="(field, index) in content_fields[tab]" :key="index">
    <v-text-field v-if="field.type == 'String'" v-model="content_data[field.name]" :label="field.name" :counter="field.length" max-width="100px"/>
    <v-text-field v-if="field.type == 'Number'" v-model="content_data[field.name]" :label="field.name" :counter="field.length" :disabled="_readOnly(field, index)"/>
    <v-menu class="my-3" v-if="field.type == 'DateTime'" :close-on-content-click="true" transition="scale-transition" max-width="290px"  min-width="290px">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-text-field v-model="content_data[field.name]" :label="field.name" hint="MM/DD/YYYY format" persistent-hint v-on="on"/>
        </template>
        <v-date-picker v-model="content_data[field.name]" no-title/>
    </v-menu>
                                                                                   <!-- this needs to bind async -->
    <v-select v-model="content_data[field.name]" v-if="field.type == 'Multiple' && _getMultipleOptions(field.value) == true" :items="multipleRelationFields" :label="field.name"/>
</div>

<script>
export default {
   methods: {
    // =============================== BETA ================================
    _getMultipleOptions(value) {
        this.$axios.get(`/data/${value}.json`).then(({data}) => {
            return true
            this.multipleRelationFields = data
        })            
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

because it's an axios.get it needs to be async loaded. but i get back an [object,promise in my v-select]
i can't load in on create or mounted, because it only needs to load data if the field is of type multiple

any solutions?

Comment: What is this `return true
            this.multipleRelationFields = data`?

Comment: the return true is to register that the data is loaded. it's in the v-if. the multiplerelationfields are the items that i'm binding in the v-select

Comment: You can't bind anything after `return`.

Comment: i did not add the data function but this.multipleRelationFields is a data property

Comment: `this.multipleRelationFields = data` - this wil not be executed.

Comment: a promise is evaluated as true..., you have to put this in data - also you dont want to call methods in v-if as those are invoke once on render...

Comment: yeah thanks, but its not whats not working. i corrected that

Comment: how do i get my dynamic data in the item binding then?

Comment: common way is to invoke in watcher or in mounted, add value to prop in data, then either use it directly or preprocess it in computed - check reactivity in depth in vue docs

Comment: ok, but if i need no data in that page. it will still render all the computed properties?

Comment: common pattern needs data prop

Comment: @Eric , please take a look at my answer, and accept if it helps you ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

## Wrap into custom component

Haven't tested it yet, but maybe it gives you an idea for a solution. You could try wrapping this "v-select" in a custom component of yours.

**Parent Component** with custom v-model

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <my-custom-select v-if="field.type == 'Multiple'" :field="field" v-model="content_data[field.name]" />
  </div>
</template>
```

**Child Component** - the v-model will be handled with prop `value` and emit of `input` event. The request will only be made when the component is being rendered, which only is when field.type is Multiple.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-select
      v-model="selection"
      :items="multipleRelationFields"
      :label="field.name"
      @input="onInput"
      />
  </div>
</tempalte>

<script>
export default {
  props : ["value","field"],
  data() {
    return {
      multipleRelationFields = [],
      selection : this.value
    }
  },
  methods : {
    onInput() {
      this.$emit('input', this.selection)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$axios.get(`/data/${this.field.value}.json`)
    .then(r => {
      this.multipleRelationFields = r.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {

    });
  }
}
</script>
```